# Funciones de Agregación en SQL

Tags: mysql

Me piden obtener esto:
1.- Mostrar el nombre y la edad del profesor que tiene la mayor edad
2.- Mostrar el nombre y la edad del profesor más joven
Y yo tengo estas tabla y al hacer las sentencias me sale la fecha bien pero el nombre no coincide con la fecha, ¿Qué puedo hacer o qué me falta?
Mis sentencias son:

***para la edad más grande***

```
select nombrep, MIN(fechanac) from profesor;
```

***para la edad más pequeña***

```
select nombrep, MIN(fechanac) from profesor;
```

[image: SENTENCIAS EN SQL]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yo haría una subconsulta para encontrar primero la menor fecha de nacimiento, y luego escogería la fila que tiene ese valor para la fecha de nacimiento.

```sql
SELECT 
  nombrep,
  fechanac
FROM
  profesor
WHERE
  fechanac = (SELECT MIN(fechanac) FROM profesor);
```

Sabiendo esto, creo que puedes hacer por cuenta propia la segunda consulta que te piden, sino, me avisas!